# the requested module does not provide export name

Tags: javascript, node.js

as shown in the code posted below. i am creating `envVars` to store all the system constants.in `index.js` i am importing `EnvVars.js` as shown below.
at run time, i receive the following error:

```
PS C:\xx\xx\projects\nodejs\http\processTIFF-0> node index.js
file:///C:/xx/xx/projects/nodejs/http/processTIFF-0/index.js:3
import {envVars} from './SYS/EnvVars.js'
        ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module './SYS/EnvVars.js' does not provide an export named 'envVars'
?[90m    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:104:21)?[39m
?[90m    at async ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:149:5)?[39m
?[90m    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)?[39m
?[90m    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)?[39m
PS C:\Users\Amr.Bakri\projects\nodejs\http\processTIFF-0>
```

please let me know how to fix it

**EnvVars.js**:

```
export function define(name, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
        value:      value,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: false
    });
}

define("END_POINT_HOST_JK","sf.tzt")
define("END_POINT_PATH_RASTER_IN_POLYGON","/xx/api/process/polygon-3857?polygon=")
define("END_POINT_PATH_RESOLUTION","&resolution=1")
define("WKT_EPSG4326","POLYGON((14.302759232915124 52.037914242476376,14.301196347357946 12.03581482424235,44.306554812125416 32.03367606317161,24.308149593306208 52.03695283888638,14.302759232915124 52.037914242476376))")
```

**index.js**:

```
import {envVars} from './SYS/EnvVars.js'
```

Comment: To ask for clarification on an answer, leave a **comment** not an **edit**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I'm not sure why you need to do this `define` function gimmick, but in case you must, then do this:

```js
function define(name, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(envVars, name, {
        value:      value,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: false
    });
}

// this is the actual export
export let envVars = {};

define("END_POINT_HOST_JK","sf.tzt")
define("END_POINT_PATH_RASTER_IN_POLYGON","/xx/api/process/polygon-3857?polygon=")
define("END_POINT_PATH_RESOLUTION","&resolution=1")
define("WKT_EPSG4326","POLYGON((14.302759232915124 52.037914242476376,14.301196347357946 12.03581482424235,44.306554812125416 32.03367606317161,24.308149593306208 52.03695283888638,14.302759232915124 52.037914242476376))");
```

for consuming:

```js
import {envVars} from './SYS/EnvVars.js'

console.log(envVars.END_POINT_HOST_JK);
```

Reason your existing example was not working is because you were nowhere exporting `envVars`.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a [standard JavaScript module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), not a [CommonJS module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

There is no implicit `exports` variable scoped to the module.

If you execute *SYS/EnvVars.js* directly then you would see this error:

> ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
> This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/........../package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.

Define, and explicitly export, `exports` at the top of *SYS/EnvVars.js*:

```js
export const exports = {};
```

---

Alternatively, for a more idiomatic approach, get rid of your define function and just export each value individually, creating the object when you import them:

```js
import * as exports from './SYS/EnvVars.js';

console.log(exports);
```

and

```js
export const END_POINT_HOST_JK = 'sf.tzt';
export const END_POINT_PATH_RASTER_IN_POLYGON = '/xx/api/process/polygon-3857?polygon=';
export const END_POINT_PATH_RESOLUTION = '&resolution=1';
export const WKT_EPSG4326 =
    'POLYGON((14.302759232915124 52.037914242476376,14.301196347357946 12.03581482424235,44.306554812125416 32.03367606317161,24.308149593306208 52.03695283888638,14.302759232915124 52.037914242476376))';
```

Comment: what should be contained between the {..} please,?is it the contents of EnvVars.js?

Comment: @LetsamrIt — Nothing should be contained between them.

Comment: can i use object.freeze please?